# How can I provide different test data to the same JUnit test?

Tags: java, dynamic, junit

I'm trying to create a dynamic JUnit Test (searching files in Directory, find matching Input/Expected File, use the right XQuery-Transformator and put the test data source folder to the right directory.)

```
ArrayList<Tuple4> t = findfiles(new String[]{"**/*.xq**"}, "D:/PROJEKTE/UDG/OSB-Projekte/"); //Routine to put these information into my Array

for( Tuple4 sub : t){
    String inp = (String) sub.c;
    if(inp.contains("DiagFisArchiveId INP HDR")){
        System.out.println("A: "+ sub.a + " B: " + sub.b + " C: "+ sub.c+ " D: "+sub.d);
    new XQueryTester((String)sub.a,(String)sub.b).testHeader((String)sub.c,(String)sub.d); 
    } else if(inp.contains("PAY")){
        System.out.println("A: "+ sub.a + " B: " + sub.b + " C: "+ sub.c+ " D: "+sub.d);

        new XQueryTester((String)sub.a,(String)sub.b).testBody((String)sub.c,(String)sub.d); 

    }
}
```

When running this I get the following output in my console:

```
A: src\conf\IsiAivResponse_XqueryTransformer\IsiAivResponse.xquery B: D:\PROJEKTE\UDG\OSB-Projekte\konf_uss_aiv\test\xquery-testdata\ C: IsiAivResponse IsiAivResponse INP PAY.xml D: IsiAivResponse IsiAivResponse EXP PAY.xml
A: src\conf\EsmArsRequest_XqueryTransformer\ArsBuilder.xquery B: D:\PROJEKTE\UDG\OSB-Projekte\konf_uss_ars\test\xquery-testdata\ C: ArsBuilder EsmArsRequest INP PAY.xml D: ArsBuilder EsmArsRequest EXP PAY.xml
A: src\conf\IsiArsHeader_XqueryTransformer\headerSetter.xq B: D:\PROJEKTE\UDG\OSB-Projekte\konf_uss_ars\test\xquery-testdata\ C: headerSetter IsiArsHeader INP PAY.xml D: headerSetter IsiArsHeader EXP HDR.xml
A: src\conf\IsiArsResponse_XqueryTransformer\response.xq B: D:\PROJEKTE\UDG\OSB-Projekte\konf_uss_ars\test\xquery-testdata\ C: response IsiArsResponse INP PAY.xml D: response IsiArsResponse EXP PAY.xml
...
```

However it says I only ran 1 Test

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.928 sec - in XQueryTest
```

is there a problem with my initialization, or is it really running "every Test" and just says it's 1?

**Edit**: I only have `1 @Test Annotation`, but how can I verify it actually tested EVERYTHING. Since in my Test-Engine (`XQueryTester`) I actually put some logging which is not printed to the console so I feel like it's not really testing it.

Comment: JUnit coints every test method as one test, regardless how many assertions you do inside. If you want to do the same test with differing test data use the `@Parameterized` testing fascillity of JUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 1 @Test obviously JUnit will say you only are running 1 test.

But what you can do to obtain your goal is add assertions for each file you need to verify. Something like this:

```
@Test
public void verifyReadFiles(){
    //Your logic here to read process files
    //Yours assertions here   
    Assert.assertThat(isLoaded(file1), is(true));
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: It's a great idea, I try to implement it and will tell the result!

Comment: But how is this excusing that my Logging wont show in my `"testBody/testHeader"` method?

Comment: @HendrikHeim i dont get your question, maybe you will need to debug a little to decide which are the best assertions to validate your code works correctly

Comment: Unfortunately I can't import my project in eclipse (maven project) because I get errors with m2e and can't find a solution (even here in stackoverflow) :/
So I'm programming in NPP atm